# Receiving "Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, sumifs

Receiving the error Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size". The lengths of the arrays are fixed so I am unclear how to resolve the error.

Attempted to fix the range by changing from column generic i.e. $I:$I to $I5:$I500 etc.
The formula is

```
=sumifs(Transactions!$G5:$G500,Transactions!$I5:$I500,E46,year(Transactions!$F5:$F500),G44)
```

Using the year() function as column F contains a formatted date, G44 contains only the year. Column I is a label i.e. "Rent" and cell E46 is the value "Rent". Column G contains the budget amount entry. There are blank cells within the columns. Looked at previous answers and don't see one that addresses this use case.

Comment: =sumifs(Transactions!$G5:$G500,Transactions!$I5:$I500,E46,   year(Transactions!$F5:$F500), ????????????, G44)"  The sumifs has three parameters for each IF... DATA-RANGE, CRITERIA-RANGE, CRITERIA

Comment: SUMIFS requires actual range input, not YEAR(Range). You could switch to MMULT as an alternative

Comment: Or, may be `SUMPRODUCT()` but using `MMULT()` will be faster. Agree with what @P.b said above ^^^

Comment: If you still want to go with `SUMIFS()` then you need to use the date range with criteria as `>=` and `<=`

Comment: Or create a helper column `YEAR(Range)` and use that column in your formula